# Bootstrap responsive button size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and would the width of three buttons within an div to be responsive based on their screen size. Currently I am just applying a fixed width to the buttons so that they remain in a row even on the smallest screens. This means the buttons are small on desktops and large tablets with a lot of spacing left and right. How can I make my buttons grow and shrink depending on screen size? Thanks

```
<div class="card-footer">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary float-left">Btn1</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Btn2</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Btn3</a>
</div>
```

[image: Responsive buttons]

Comment: width 33% does not work for it?

Comment: Mate, 33% didn't but just tried 30% and it worked, realised the padding was pushing it over. Wow feel so dumb! I'll have to delete this :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this way

```
<div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-between">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Btn1</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary m-0 btn-block mx-4">Btn2</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-block m-0 btn-primary">Btn3</a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/3504rLso/3/

Comment: with `style = "font-size:5vw;"` it works very well.